# Two files with saved iptables rules

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall

I have got CentOs and here are my all saved rules /etc/sysconfig/iptables.
I want to create another file with rules which will be loaded form systemctl start iptables.service as well.
Have you got any idea how can I do this?

Maybe I can do something like "include /etc/sysconfig/iptables2" inside "/etc/sysconfig/iptables"?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a systemd unit that loads the second file and in the unit dependencies you put:

```
After=iptables.service
```

Then once it’s enabled, it’ll automatically start after iptables.service on boot. If you want to make it run every time you restart the service you can use `PartOf` as well as `After`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have a startup script and restore both rule files on it?

like `/etc/init.d/load-iptables-rules`

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore /etc/sysconfig/iptables
iptables-restore /etc/sysconfig/iptables2
```

Comment: It doesn't resolve my problem. After systemctl restart iptables I don't have this rules.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can tweak the iptables-service init script for this

> /usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# iptables  Start iptables firewall
#
# chkconfig: 2345 08 92
# description:  Starts, stops and saves iptables firewall
#
# config: /etc/sysconfig/iptables
# config: /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: iptables
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: start and stop iptables firewall
# Description: Start, stop and save iptables firewall
### END INIT INFO

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

IPTABLES=iptables
IPTABLES_DATA=/etc/sysconfig/$IPTABLES
IPTABLES_FALLBACK_DATA=${IPTABLES_DATA}.fallback
IPTABLES_CONFIG=/etc/sysconfig/${IPTABLES}-config
IPTABLES_CONFIG2=/etc/sysconfig/${IPTABLES}-config2  # your second iptables file
...
...
# Load firewall configuration.
[ -f "$IPTABLES_CONFIG" ] && . "$IPTABLES_CONFIG" && . "$IPTABLES_CONFIG2" # load your file
...
...
...
```

2. you can use cron tabs also (disable iptables service)

> ```
> @reboot iptables-restore /etc/sysconfig/iptables  
> @reboot iptables-restore /etc/sysconfig/iptables2
> ```